Is the Convex Hull of a Compact Set Without 0 Closed
Let $X$ be a locally convex space and $K\subseteq X$ a compact subset not containing 0. We know that the convex hull $\mathrm{co}(K)$ of $K$ is not necessarily compact, but is it closed? Wikipedia seems to imply this, though they don't place conditions on $X$ and they cite Rockafeller 1970, which is also vague in the conditions on $X$. Are they implicitly assuming $X$ is in Euclidean space or does this hold for a larger class of spaces?

Convince yourself that the convex hull contains all of its interior points and boundary points. This will imply it's closed.

In a general locally convex TVS, the convex hull of a totally bounded subset will be again totally bounded (it is in Rudin's "Functional Analysis").

@MoisheKohan.  Ah you are right, the question already has an answer and has the same counterexample taken from Alipranti's book. I voted to close the question.

@MoisheKohan Fixed it.

The assumption about $0$ makes absolutely no difference. Think about this for a little bit.

@MoisheKohan What if we assume 0 is not in the set at all? It seems to me to change the nature of the hull. Since then none of the $x_n$ in the counterexample lie within it.

This will make no difference either.

@MoisheKohan Ah I see, my apologies.

I think Rockafellar 1970 deals with $\mathbb{R}^n$ mainly?

This is not true. Take $X=\ell^2$ with the norm topology and $K=\{u_n \colon n \ge 1\} \cup \{0\}$ where $u_n = (0,\dots, 0, 1/n,0,\dots)$. Then $K$ is compact since $\|u_n\|_2 =1/n\to 0$.  Since $0 \in K$ you can easily convince yourself that
$$ co  (K) = \left \{  \sum_{i=1}^k t_i u_i \,\colon t_i \ge 0  \text{ and } \sum_{i=1}^k t_i \le 1 \right\} $$
(the crucial difference being that the sum $\sum_i t_i \le 1$ and not $\sum_i t_i =1$). Take
$$ x_n = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac {1}{2^i} u_i \in co(K) .$$
Then $x_n \to x = (\frac 12 \frac 1 1,  \frac{1}{2^2} \frac 12, \dots,  \frac{1}{2^n} \frac 1n,\dots)$ in $\ell^2$ and $x \notin co(K)$. This is because any element of $co(K)$ is a sequence which is eventually zero.

My apologies, in Rockafeller, he stipulates that 0 is not on the boundary of $K$.
